# Python 3.6.6 : The System cannot find the path specified : D:\\Visual Studio\\ VC\\ Platform SDK \\ Lib

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was installing a few modules like TA-Lib , bitmex but I am getting an error that The System cannot find the path specified:

> D:\Visual Studio\ VC\ Platform SDK \ Lib

Python version is 3.6.6

Comment: Can you navigate to that path? As in copy-paste it into the path text box in your file explorer, exactly as it is?

Comment: @mypetlion no I can't nevigate to that path...upto VC I can but there is not folder named Platform SDK

Answer (score 0):

Abel to solve it --

Go to visual studio --> File --> New Project --> c++

so it will show missing file to download and after downloading it installed those modules and it got done without any error.